# Hide the corner of <textarea>

Tags: html, css, textarea

On Firefox (at least), when we disable the border of a textarea, its bottom right corner is still visible. How can we remove it?

```css
textarea:focus {
  outline: solid;
}

textarea {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea>Hello</textarea>
```

Comment: textarea{
    resize:none;
}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to disables resizing behavior in this case

```
textarea {
  border: none;
  resize: none;
}
```

Comment: But if I want to get the resizing feature again when I select the textarea, what should I put in textarea:focus?

Answer (score 4):

Try `resize:none` for `<textarea>`.

```
textarea{
  resize:none;
}
```